# Proving that the function $f(x) = 4 - \sqrt{x^2 -16}$ is bounded

Tags: functions

I found the Domain, and it was divided into 2 cases:

Case(1): $x \leq -4$ and from this I reached $f(x) \leq 4$.

Case(2): $x \geq 4$ and from this I reached $\sqrt{x^2 -16} \geq \sqrt{-12} $.

But in the second step I stopped because taking square root of $-ve$ number is not allowed in our course. so I considered case(2) as a refused case, am I right?

Now, finally I can say about the function that it is not bounded as it is bounded above only.... am I right?

Comment: well $y=4-\sqrt{16-x^2}$ would be bounded (it is a circle $(y-4)^2+x^2=16$) but this form is not, limit in infinity is $-\infty$. Also $x\ge 4\implies x^2-16\ge 16-16\ge 0$ not $12$.

Comment: First, note that $\sqrt{x} \ge 0$ for all $x \ge 0$, which implies that $f(x) \ge 4$ for all $|x| \ge 4$.  Thus the function is bounded above by 4.  On the other hand, $\sqrt{x^2} \to +\infty$ as $|x| \to +\infty$, which implies that $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $|x|\to+\infty$.  Thus the function has no lower bound.

Comment: @XanderHenderson you are reversing the third inequality.

Comment: Oi... I knew what I meant... $f(x) \le 4$ for all $|x|\ge 4$.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitvely, as $x$ gets large in magnitude $\sqrt {x^2-16}$ is close to $|x|$ because the $16$ doesn't matter, so you can make the expression as negative as you want.  That shows that there is no lower bound.  To make it formal, I should be able to challenge you with an $N$ and you should be able to find an $x$ such that $|f(x)| \gt N$.  With the thought above you should be able to find that.   As a square root is always at least $0$, you have an easy upper bound of $4$.

Answer (score 0):

It is bounded above
(it is at most 4)
but not bounded below
(goes to $-\infty$
as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

A little more formal.

Upper bound: $4,$

since $\sqrt{x^2-16} \ge 0$,  for

$x\in D$ (domain).

No lower bound :

Consider the sequence:

$(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} =n^2 +16$.

$y_n:= f(x_n) = 4 - n.$

Limit $y_{n \rightarrow \infty} = - \infty.$